# google suite integration with azure active directory

Tags: azure-active-directory

I was trying to integrate azure active directory with google suite, but in enterprise catalog i cant find product **Google Apps**, following this tutorial https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/saas-apps/google-apps-tutorial.

Anybody knows how to integrate AD with Google Suite with Products available in catalog ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just checked with my own subscription.
It looks like they have updated the Enterprise Application to be called G Suite now instead of Google Apps, but the picture in the documentation has not been updated. The text does however ask you to look for G Suite instead of Google Apps.

Try searching for G Suite instead of Google Apps in step 4 of the tutorial and see if you can find it then.

[image: G Suite]